# Pass parameter to method in controller via ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm sure this is probably easy but I'm having the hardest time finding the answer!

I have a method in my controller defined as:

```
public function update_news($newsID = NULL) { 
//updates news article
}
```

I'm trying to use that method as the url in an ajax call for example:

```
     jQuery.ajax({
            url: "manage/project/update_news(5)",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
...
```

I get the error POST https://dev.vmc.w3.uvm.edu/xana/manage/project/update_news(5) 400 (Bad Request)

How do I pass the parameter to the controller function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you work with a framework but I think the url in your ajax could be :

```
manage/project/update_news/5
```

or

```
manage/project/update_news?newsID=5
```